# JQuery Error Making my Mind Loop

Tags: jquery, validation

This is the final step before pushing errors for inline validation:

$(("#fn_fn").parent('div:equ(0)')).addClass('item-error');

it hits this line and gives the following:

"Object doesn't support this Property Or Method"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your inner selector is missing the `$` sign `("#fn_fn").parent('div:equ(0)')`

Try this:

```
$("#fn_fn").parent("div").addClass("item-error");
```

What is `equ`? Did you mean `eq`? If so, it would be redundant since `parent()` only returns 1 element.

http://api.jquery.com/eq/

http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: It refers to the parent of the parent of fn

Comment: @will - You're trying to run `.parent()` on a string, you need the syntax like hunter has in the answer.

Comment: @will, what you have is close but you need to wrap your inner code with a $ like so: `$("#fn_fn").parents("div:first").addClass("item-error");`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your syntax. I'll take a stab that perhaps you meant:

```
$('#fn_fn').parent('div').addClass('item-error');
```

or similar:

```
$('#fn_fn').parents('div:eq(0)').addClass('item-error');
```

Did you mean to use the [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) filter? `equ` isn't valid.